# Radio button only select first value in ionic when submitting to database

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this group of radio buttons:

```
<ion-list radio-group >
<ion-list-header>
Location
</ion-list-header>

<ion-item>
<ion-label>Rural</ion-label>
<ion-radio value="rural" class="radio" name="schloc" #schloc ></ion-radio>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label>Urban</ion-label>
<ion-radio value="urban" class="radio" name="schloc" #schloc ></ion-radio>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label>Other</ion-label>
<ion-radio value="other" class="radio" name="schloc" #schloc ></ion-radio>
</ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

The problem is if I pick **Other** which is the third radio button and submit, **Rural** will be the one to submit which is the first one.

And, it also occur with all the radio buttons. Only the first one get submitted.

I used `@ViewChild("schloc")schloc;` to hold the values of the radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

`schloc: any` // define

```
  <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="schloc">
    <ion-list-header>
      Location
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Rural</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="rural"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Urban</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="urban"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Other</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="other"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

when you are submitting data, use `this.schloc`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `FormControl` for it, so your code would look something like

```
<ion-list radio-group formControlName="yourFormControl">
<ion-list-header>
Location
</ion-list-header>

<ion-item>
<ion-label>Rural</ion-label>
<ion-radio value="rural" class="radio" name="schloc" #schloc ></ion-radio>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label>Urban</ion-label>
<ion-radio value="urban" class="radio" name="schloc" #schloc ></ion-radio>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label>Other</ion-label>
<ion-radio value="other" class="radio" name="schloc" #schloc ></ion-radio>
</ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

and then in your `TS` file: `valueToSubmit = yourFormGroup.get('formControlName').value`